# Spring-boot:run funciona pero java -jar falla

Tags: java, webservice, spring, ssl, https

Estoy teniendo un problema al ejecutar con java -jar.

La aplicación es un WS de integración (expone un endpoint cuyas operaciones llaman a un WS de terceros). 
La aplicación funcionaba correctamente con http, pero al añadir el tercero un certificado propio y forzar el uso de https, ha dejado de funcionar.

He creado el jks, y he conseguido que genere las clases del wsdl del tercero. La aplicación compila y ejecutando "mvn spring-boot:run -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=MiJks.jks" funciona correctamente. Si por el contrario utilizo "java -jar Miapp.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=MiJks.jks", no es capaz de crear los beans de los servicios del 3o.

Para generar el código del wsdl del 3o,utilizo jaxws-maven-plugin de codehaus.

Esta es la definición del bean dentro del application-context:

¿Qué está fallando?¿Qué diferencia hay entre ejecutar java a través de maven y ejecutar el java directamente?

Gracias de antemano,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente se ha solucionado usando la opción -D antes que -jar en la ejecución del comando java.

Gracias por la respuesta Raúl García

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a introducir en la ejecución maven el siguiente comando:

> mvn package spring-boot:run -D javax.net.ssl.trustStore=MiJks.jks

Este comando compila y empaqueta todas las dependencias del codigo en el .jar, luego prueba a arrancar el programa desde el .jar usando el comando java que usaste antes, si eso no lo arregla creo que el problema va a ser de esa variable global que injectas...